# How do you determine which plot has smaller or larger residuals from a box plot?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, regression-analysis

Which plot has the smallest residuals?

[image: residuals on box plot]

Answer (score 0):

There is no formula for determining this, you just have to make a judgement based on what we can infer about the data from the box plots. A set of points with higher variance will have larger residuals than a set of points with lower variance.

Comment: So should it be the plot with the black dots closer to the box? Color I for instance?

Comment: The variance of a set of points will typically correlate with a larger IQR, and more outliers.